# Using GREP in WINDOWS directories

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, terminal, grep

I have a grep command in BASH to find a specific string pattern and write it to an output.txt:

```
grep -rihn "string1.*string2.*string3" . > output.txt
```

But how do  I do the same in Windows Powershell?
Apparently FINDSTR has some similar functionalities, but replacing the above code with FINDSTR writes nothing to my output.txt.

Comment: You're looking for `Select-String`.  `$stringvalue | Select-String -Pattern '\d{3}'`

Comment: See [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6) cmdlet in PowerShell!